# Avoid "==" in Encrypting string

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, encryption

Below is my code. Every time I encrypt the string, it is giving string as "==" in the end.

How can I avoid that.

```
  Private Function Encrypt(clearText As String) As String
    Dim EncryptionKey As String = "MAKV2SPBNI99212"
    Dim clearBytes As Byte() = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(clearText)
    Using encryptor As Aes = Aes.Create()
        Dim pdb As New Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, New Byte() {&H49, &H76, &H61, &H6E, &H20, &H4D, _
         &H65, &H64, &H76, &H65, &H64, &H65, _
         &H76})
        encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32)
        encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16)
        Using ms As New MemoryStream()
            Using cs As New CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write)
                cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length)
                cs.Close()
            End Using
            clearText = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray())
        End Using
    End Using
    Return clearText
End Function
```

Comment: You can't, if you are encoding it in base64, unless you change the number of bytes.

Comment: I am ready to change the bytes. Can you please give me the sample code ?

Comment: You can't if you want to decode it again, it is part of the encryption.

Comment: Can you please give me other way to encrypt the string ?

Comment: I don't understand, why do you care if the encryption has == at the end? What is your goal in removing it?

Comment: @N4TKD Hello, I am passing that enrypted string in email to others. In the email, those "==" are not getting underlined. So, if user clicks on the link, URL is missing that "==" and resulting in error

Comment: Maybe you should use something else like Guid generated number and not the encrypted data as the url see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid.aspx

Answer (score 1):

That's a result of [base-64 encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). It's just there to indicate that the length of the input byte array was not a multiple of 3, and is necessary for properly decoding the string. It's nothing to worry about, and it doesn't indicate that there's anything wrong with your encryption algorithm.

If you really need to prevent it, make sure the byte array you pass to `ToBase64String` has a length that is a multiple of 3, possibly by padding the array with zeroes (but then you'd have to be able to strip those zeros off after you decode the string).

Comment: Hello, I am passing that enrypted string in email to others. In the email, those "==" are not getting underlined. So, if user clicks on the link, he is missing that "==" and resulting in error.

Comment: @user1144271 What about encoding the URL (`=` encodes to `%3D`) or replacing the `=` with a different character (e.g. `-`)?

Comment: I think it works but is there any standard way to encrypt and decrypt the string ?

Comment: @user1144271 There's nothing wrong with how you're encrypting / decrypting the string or which how your encoding, but `=` is a special character in a URL, so you'd have to handle that separately if you want send it as part of a URL.